# Отправка писем через SMTP phpmailer

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

На локальном сервере отправка писем работает, но при переносе сайта на хостинг Timeweb письма не отправляются. В консоли причина ошибки: SMTP connect() failed. https://git…ode: 111 Additional SMTP info: Connection refused.
Изначальный код:

```php
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.yandex.ru';
$mail->Username   = 'login';
$mail->Password   = '*****';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->setFrom('login@yandex.ru', 'Name');
```

Пробовала менять сервер на smtp.timeweb.ru, та же ошибка.

```php
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.timeweb.ru';
$mail->Username   = 'login';
$mail->Password   = '*****';
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->setFrom('login@****.ru', 'Name');
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!